# Connect to Web Service in Java Project using a certificate .cer

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, certificate

Good Morning:

I have several problems to connect a server I am deploying.

First, I have a web service wsdl in a server I control.
And second, I am programming a java client to connect via https with 8443 port to tomcat webservice to return the data.

I firstly installed the pfx certificate on the server, and it works.

Second, I downloaded the client .cer certificate file from the browser and I have to use it to call the webservice https with 8443 and I am having the same error always.

```
 AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:vm6145260

javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.b7f2.ws.service.ImplLoginSoapBindingStub.validaLogin(ImplLoginSoapBindingStub.java:157)
    at com.b7f2.ws.service.ImplLoginProxy.validaLogin(ImplLoginProxy.java:51)
    at com.b7f2.ws.client.WindowPrincipal.enviarMatricula(WindowPrincipal.java:105)
    at com.b7f2.ws.client.WindowPrincipal.access$1(WindowPrincipal.java:97)
    at com.b7f2.ws.client.WindowPrincipal$2.actionPerformed(WindowPrincipal.java:216)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I used thie same webservice first with 8080 port and it worked perfectly, but now with the certificate it doesn't work.

Can anybody explain to me, which have I to do with the .cer file in the client java project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, you probably have to set these properties :

- -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore
- -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keystore_password

Of course, the keystore contains your certificate (.cer)

Can you post your client code ?

Comment: I cannot post the client code. I simply used a class extends java.rmi.Remote as connection. And then.

Comment: Call it from the main class, a object is sent to the class to validate the access and the webservice returned the data. But I don't know which code have I to write on the client (Eclipse)

Comment: There are two things you need to configure. The first will be the trustStore on the client side, to allow the server to communicate with the client. The second is an optional keystore (the one I mentionned in my answer) which is used for the client to authenticate on the server. Which one exactly do you need ? Maybe both ?

Comment: The pfx certificate has been installed sucessfulty in the server, and https are returned on the web browser normally.

Comment: The issue now, it's to now which code have I to write on client server java project to connect, to avoid the SSL handshake exception (i don't know if any action is required on the server apart of installing the pfx certificate)

Comment: You should not have to write any code on the client side.
Just run your application or your server with the above environment parameters.
If you really want to do it programmatically, you can do the following before your webservice call :
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","path_to_keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","keystore_password");

Comment: I tried, but before it was called http://www.blablabla.com:8080/Login, now I changed that to https://www.blablabla.com:8443/Login, and that error I first wrote on the header appeares. I even tried to write the keystore on the code before calling the web service, but same error happens again and again. AGGH

Comment: AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
 {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:vm611000C

javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:

Comment: Oups sorry, I mixed up different things here.
The parameters to set are the trustStore parameters, not the keyStore ones.
The idea is to 'validate' that the server possess the right certificate, so you need to configure a trustStore, with the parameters : 

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",path_to_your_cacerts_file);